# How to create a .crt store file containing a certificate chain from a PKCS12 one?

Tags: bouncycastle, jce

I have a PKCS12 file containing a certificate chain and a private key.
I would like to use BouncyCastle to create a CRT file with that cert chain, the same way we can do using OpenSSL command-line tool:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfilename.pfx] -clcerts -nokeys -out [certificatename.crt]
```

I was already able to load the pkcs12 Keystore and obtain the certificates:

```
Certificate[] certs = pKeyStore.getCertificateChain(pAlias);
```

But I wasn't able to find a store builder for a CRT file that could accept the array of certificates above...

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is `org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter` in **bcpkix**. You can use its `write` method to encode all sorts of JCE interfaces (`X509Certificate`, `X509CRL`, `PublicKey`, `PrivateKey`, `KeyPair`) to a PEM file.

In your case:

```java
final JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(System.out);
for (final Certificate cert : certs) {
    pemWriter.write(cert);
}
```